# Export MySQL Database from HeidiSQL to SQL Server. Problem with simple quotes

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ssms, heidisql

I have a remote MySQL DB in a hosting that I need to export to my local SQL Server.
I use Heidi SQL to connect the DB and I use the Export to single .sql file
The problem is that the DB is 5GB and the .sql file is 2.3GB. So I can't open the .sql with SSMS because it says that the file is to big.
So I try to run the command sqlcmd on console >sqlcmd -S localhost\SQLEXPRESS -i "C:\backup\file.sql"
but it fails because of the simple quotes:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         IP
-- Versión del servidor:         5.5.60-0+deb7u1-log - (Debian)
-- SO del servidor:              debian-linux-gnu
-- HeidiSQL Versión:             12.0.0.6468
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `MyDB` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `MyDB`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Account` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

It should not be this extrange quote (``) it should be normal quote (''). Is there a way to generate the .sql script from Heidi with normal quotes so I can execute it in the cmd?? I can't change manually with crt+f because I can't open the 2.3GB file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL syntaxes differ between MySQL and SQL Server. When trying to use direct database dump, you will likely have other incompatibilities as well.

Try using the [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54257) instead.